# Force table to fit on page

Tags: tables, floats, floating

I am creating a PDF document where I want to fit a lot of information on just one page. At the bottom of the document, there is a table. When I compile my PDF, the table jumps over onto the next page, although there is plenty of space for it at the bottom of the document. I've searched the web thoroughly for a fitting solution, but none of the suggestions work. I have in some instances managed to force it up by using a negative `\vspace` underneath the table but this does not look good on the PDF document since it creates a big empty space at the bottom. I'll include a MWE below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,icelandic,a4paper]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class

\usepackage{lipsum}                 
\usepackage{hyperref}                                   
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage[margin=0.2in,bottom=0pt]{geometry} %ATHAHT
    \textheight=700px
    %\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.3in}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}   

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{minipage}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------


%%% Begin Document
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\vspace{1mm}

\FloatBarrier

\textbf{References}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{tabular}[H]{lll}
Dr. Spock & Spockmeister & spock@spock.com\\
Dr. Strangelove  & Bomb lover & strange@love.com\\ 
Dr. Frankenstein & Monster & franken@stein.com\\ 
Dr. Whatever & Whatever & what@ever.com\\  
%\vspace{-9mm}
\end{tabular}

\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add option `showframe` to the options of package `geometry`. Then, you will see, that the place left on the page is much smaller than the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I see when I add this option is a horizontal line across the first page which I suppose represents the bottom margin. Why does it put the margin this high? I thought I had defined a margin of 0 pts for the bottom of the page with the geometry option margin=0pt.

Comment: @arnortumi: Your setting contradict one another. Setting `margin` and `bottom` are okay; that inherently defines the text block. Subsequently setting `textheight` redefines the text block dimensions (vertically), which then inherently redefines the margins.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you! Solved. And lesson learned :)

Comment: `tabular` does not have an `H` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visually your table may fit, but technically there is no room available on the page for the table. This is because of your layout settings in [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry):

Setting `margin` and `bottom` together is fine, as `margin` also sets `bottom`, which is then overwritten with an explicit call to set `bottom`. Note that this inherently defines the text block, since it's contained within the margins. However, subsequently setting the `textheight` actually redefines the margins; more specifically, it redefines `bottom` since the text block is laid out from the top of the page.

In your case, either set the `margin`s (and `bottom`) or the text block's `textheight`, but not both as they reset one another.